# Как создать свою Activity которая будет отображаться при включении экрана устройства?

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализуется данный механизм, как на скриншоте? Нужно чтобы при нажатии пользователем на кнопку выключения, сразу же после включении экрана отображалась моя активность. Я пробовал использовать `BroadcastReceiver` и отслеживал событие `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT`. Но это событие наступает уже после того, когда экран разблокирован. Буду признателен получить ответ на мой вопрос! С наилучшими пожеланиями, Сергей!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Comment: Ziens, Вы были совершенно правы! Огромное спасибо Вам за помощь. Скажу только, что для отслеживания этого события нам нужно регистрировать широковещательный приёмник с IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON") не в манифесте а Activity или в Service.

Comment: @Сергей, опишите, пж-та, решение в ответе)

Comment: Доброго времени суток! С первой частью вопроса я разобрался. Отслеживать событие включение экрана получается. Для этого регистрируем класс унаследованный от BroadcastReceiver в Activity или в Service с IntentFilter: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
Теперь вопрос по поводу того, как сделать чтобы при наступлении этого события при открытии моей активности у неё был приоритет над активностью блокировщика? Есть вариант использовать у активности стиль диалогового окна, тогда оно должно будет появиться выше всех активностей и фрагментов. Возможно есть ещё какие-то другие варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Первая часть решённой проблемы. Создаём класс унаследованный от BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class LockscreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public LockscreenReceiver() {

}

public static final String TAG = "myPlayer";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
          if ( intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LockscreenReceiver");
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);
             }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error BroadcastReceiver", e);
    }
}
}
```

Регистрируем наш ресивер либо в активности, либо в сервисе. В том месте от куда мы хотим динамически управлять слушателем. В моём случае это активность. И передаём BroadcastReceiver фильтр намерений: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON:

```
private LockscreenReceiver lockscreenReceiver = new LockscreenReceiver();
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.registerReceiver(lockscreenReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"));
}
```

Comment: Политика сервиса Q&A такова, что в одном вопросе может быть только одна проблема. Для решения другой проблемы создайте новый вопрос.